# React native Paper Radio Buttons not remaining Checked individually after tapping them after onchange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a bit new to react native and I am using React Native Paper from the below link
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button.html
to implement radio buttons
I have a screen that generates radio button components at random using array destructuring.
The problem is that the Radio Buttons do not remain Checked individually after tapping them after on change event
Everything works except that the radio buttons don't remain checked and it checks all rows with same name option
See my code below

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react"
import { View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, ImageBackground, ScrollView, Alert } from "react-native"
import { StackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import { Button, Text } from "../../components"
import { NavigatorParamList } from "../../navigators"
import { Images } from "../../config"
import { store } from "../../store"
import { RadioButton } from "react-native-paper"
import axios from "axios"
import { SEND_FEEDBACK_URL, showErrorAlert } from "../../utils/constants"
import {
  BOTTOM_HALF,
  CONTINUE,
  CONTINUE_TEXT,
  FOOTER_CONTENT,
  FULL,
  LABEL,
  RED_ACTION_LINK,
  RED_ACTION_STYLES,
  REGULAR_TEXT,
  SMALLL_TEXT,
  SMALLL_TEXT_C,
  SUBJECT,
  textArea,
  textAreaContainer,
} from "./send-feedback-styles"
import Loader from "../../components/loader/loader"
import { setImputArrayValue } from "../../reducers/imputArrayReducer"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"

export const SendFeedbackScreen: FC<StackScreenProps<NavigatorParamList, "Send">> = observer(
  ({ navigation }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [checkBoxStatus, setCheckBoxStatus] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [disabledStat, setDisabledStat] = useState(false)

    const tempQuestIdArray = []

    /*
    let tempStr0: string
    let tempStr1: string
    let tempStr2: string
    let tempStr3: string
    let tempStr4: string
    */

    const [freeText, setFreeText] = useState("")

  
    const [tempStr0, setTempStr0] = useState("")
    const [tempStr1, setTempStr1] = useState("")
    const [tempStr2, setTempStr2] = useState("")
    const [tempStr3, setTempStr3] = useState("")
    const [tempStr4, setTempStr4] = useState("")


    console.log("<<<<<<BEFORE fetching stored token")
    const token = store.getState().token.tokenValue
    console.log("<<<<<<<PROFILE TOKEN>>>>>>>>>")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(token))
    console.log("<<<<<<<PROFILE TOKEN>>>>>>>>>")
    console.log("<<<<<<BEFORE fetching stored Sales Agent Id")
    const salesAgentId = store.getState().salesAgentId.salesAgentIdValue
    console.log("<<<<<<< SALES Agent id >>>>>>>>>")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(salesAgentId))
    console.log("<<<<<<< SALES Agent id >>>>>>>>>")

    const getSuccessScreen = () => navigation.navigate("Successful")

    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${token}` },
    }

    const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: SEND_FEEDBACK_URL,
    })

    const barcodeId = store.getState().barcodeId.barcodeIdValue
    const CustomerId = store.getState().customerId.customerIdValue
    const DeviceId = store.getState().deviceId.deviceIdValue
    const questionsArray = store.getState().questionArray.questionArrayValue
    const CustomerName = store.getState().customerName.customerNameValue

    const QUESTIONS = questionsArray

    const renderInputRadios = () => {
      const qArray = QUESTIONS

      return (
        <View>
          {qArray.map((i, key) => {
            console.info("key >>> ", key)
            console.info("i.id >>> ", i.id)
            tempQuestIdArray.push(i.id)
            return (
              <View key={key}>
                <View style={RED_ACTION_STYLES}>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT}>{i.questionWord}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={RED_ACTION_LINK}>
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>1</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="0"
                      status={tempStr0 === "0" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr0)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("0"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr0 !== "0") {
                          setTempStr0("0")
                        } else {
                          setTempStr0("")
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>2</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="1"
                      status={tempStr1 === "1" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr1)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("1"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr1 !== "1") {
                          setTempStr1("1")
                        } else {
                          setTempStr1("")
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>3</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="2"
                      status={tempStr2 === "2" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr2)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("2"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr2 !== "2") {
                          setTempStr2("2")
                        } else {
                          setTempStr2("")
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>4</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="3"
                      status={tempStr3 === "3" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr3)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("3"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr3 !== "3") {
                          setTempStr3("3")
                        } else {
                          setTempStr3("")
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>5</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="4"
                      status={tempStr4 === "4" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr4)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("4"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr4 !== "4") {
                          setTempStr4("4")
                        } else {
                          setTempStr4("")
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            )
          })}
          <View style={textAreaContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={textArea}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder="Type something"
              placeholderTextColor="#707070"
              numberOfLines={5}
              multiline={true}
              value={freeText}
              onChangeText={(freeText) => setFreeText(freeText)}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }

    const onSendFeedbacck = async () => {
      if (!checkBoxStatus) {
        showErrorAlert("Your Response")
        return
      }
      if (!freeText) {
        showErrorAlert("Your Response")
        return
      }
      setLoading(true)

      console.log("<<< inside onSendFeedbacck >>>>>")
      // 1. display inputArray
      const inputArray = checkBoxStatus
      console.log("<<< inputArray >>>>>", inputArray)

      // 2. display inputArray Length
      // console.log("<<< items.length >>>>>", inputArray)

      const AnswerArray = inputArray

      console.log("AnswerArray ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArray)

      const AnswerArrayStr = JSON.stringify(AnswerArray)
      console.log("AnswerArrayStr ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArrayStr)

      const AnswerArrayObj = JSON.parse(AnswerArrayStr)
      console.log("AnswerArrayObj ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArrayObj)

      const dataToSend = {
        customerId: CustomerId,
        productDeviceId: DeviceId,
        questions: AnswerArrayObj,
        otherComments: freeText,
        salesAgentId: salesAgentId,
      }

      console.log("dataToSend ..>>>>>>>> ", dataToSend)
      try {
        console.log("<<<<<<<BEFORE RESPONSE FOR SEND FEEDBACK >>>>>>>>>")
        console.log("dataToSend >> ", dataToSend)
        console.log("config >> ", config)

        const res = await api.post("/", dataToSend, config)
        console.log(res)
        console.log("Res >> ", res)
        console.log("<<<<<<<AFTER RESPONSE FOR SEND_FEEDBACK_URL >>>>>>>>>")

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
        if (res.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
          // Get Response
          setLoading(false)
          getSuccessScreen()
        } else {
          console.log("<<<<<<<ERRRRRROR>>>>>>>>>")
          setLoading(false)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        setLoading(false)
        Alert.alert("Error " + err)
      }
    }

    return (
      <ImageBackground source={Images.bg} style={FULL}>
        <Loader loading={loading} />
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={BOTTOM_HALF}>
            <SafeAreaView>
              <Text style={SUBJECT}>Device Identified</Text>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>Barcode ID</Text>
                <Text style={REGULAR_TEXT}>{barcodeId}</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>Customer </Text>
                <Text style={REGULAR_TEXT}>{CustomerName}</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>
                  Please Fill the Form Below to by selecting an option between 1 to 5 for each
                  question to Provide More Information on This Device
                </Text>
              </View>

              {renderInputRadios()}

              <View style={FOOTER_CONTENT}>
                <Button
                  testID="next-screen-button"
                  style={CONTINUE}
                  textStyle={CONTINUE_TEXT}
                  tx="inside.send_feedback"
                  onPress={onSendFeedbacck}
                />
              </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    )
  },
)
```

I also tried this method below

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react"
import { View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, ImageBackground, ScrollView, Alert } from "react-native"
import { StackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import { Button, Text } from "../../components"
import { NavigatorParamList } from "../../navigators"
import { Images } from "../../config"
import { store } from "../../store"
import { RadioButton } from "react-native-paper"
import axios from "axios"
import { SEND_FEEDBACK_URL, showErrorAlert } from "../../utils/constants"
import {
  BOTTOM_HALF,
  CONTINUE,
  CONTINUE_TEXT,
  FOOTER_CONTENT,
  FULL,
  LABEL,
  RED_ACTION_LINK,
  RED_ACTION_STYLES,
  REGULAR_TEXT,
  SMALLL_TEXT,
  SMALLL_TEXT_C,
  SUBJECT,
  textArea,
  textAreaContainer,
} from "./send-feedback-styles"
import Loader from "../../components/loader/loader"
import { setImputArrayValue } from "../../reducers/imputArrayReducer"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"

export const SendFeedbackScreen: FC<StackScreenProps<NavigatorParamList, "Send">> = observer(
  ({ navigation }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [checkBoxStatus, setCheckBoxStatus] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [disabledStat, setDisabledStat] = useState(false)

    const tempQuestIdArray = []

  
    let tempStr0: string
    let tempStr1: string
    let tempStr2: string
    let tempStr3: string
    let tempStr4: string
  

    const [freeText, setFreeText] = useState("")


    console.log("<<<<<<BEFORE fetching stored token")
    const token = store.getState().token.tokenValue
    console.log("<<<<<<<PROFILE TOKEN>>>>>>>>>")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(token))
    console.log("<<<<<<<PROFILE TOKEN>>>>>>>>>")
    console.log("<<<<<<BEFORE fetching stored Sales Agent Id")
    const salesAgentId = store.getState().salesAgentId.salesAgentIdValue
    console.log("<<<<<<< SALES Agent id >>>>>>>>>")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(salesAgentId))
    console.log("<<<<<<< SALES Agent id >>>>>>>>>")

    const getSuccessScreen = () => navigation.navigate("Successful")

    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${token}` },
    }

    const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: SEND_FEEDBACK_URL,
    })

    const barcodeId = store.getState().barcodeId.barcodeIdValue
    const CustomerId = store.getState().customerId.customerIdValue
    const DeviceId = store.getState().deviceId.deviceIdValue
    const questionsArray = store.getState().questionArray.questionArrayValue
    const CustomerName = store.getState().customerName.customerNameValue

    const QUESTIONS = questionsArray

    const renderInputRadios = () => {
      const qArray = QUESTIONS

      return (
        <View>
          {qArray.map((i, key) => {
            console.info("key >>> ", key)
            console.info("i.id >>> ", i.id)
            tempQuestIdArray.push(i.id)
            return (
              <View key={key}>
                <View style={RED_ACTION_STYLES}>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT}>{i.questionWord}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={RED_ACTION_LINK}>
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>1</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="0"
                      status={tempStr0 === "0" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr0)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("0"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr0 !== "0") {
                          tempStr0 = "0"
                        } else {
                          tempStr0 = ""
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>2</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="1"
                      status={tempStr1 === "1" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr1)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("1"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr1 !== "1") {
                          tempStr1 = "1"
                        } else {
                          tempStr0 = ""
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>3</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="2"
                      status={tempStr2 === "2" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr2)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("2"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr2 !== "2") {
                          tempStr2 = "2"
                        } else {
                          tempStr0 = ""
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>4</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="3"
                      status={tempStr3 === "3" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr3)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("3"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr3 !== "3") {
                          tempStr3 = "3"
                        } else {
                          tempStr0 = ""
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>5</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="4"
                      status={tempStr4 === "4" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> tempStr ", tempStr4)
                        const answer = {
                          questionId: i.id,
                          answer: Number("4"),
                        }
                        setCheckBoxStatus([...checkBoxStatus, answer])
                        console.info("BOOOOOM >>> ", answer)
                        console.info("tempAnsArray >>> ", checkBoxStatus)
                        if (tempStr4 !== "4") {
                          tempStr4 = "4"
                        } else {
                          tempStr0 = ""
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            )
          })}
          <View style={textAreaContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={textArea}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder="Type something"
              placeholderTextColor="#707070"
              numberOfLines={5}
              multiline={true}
              value={freeText}
              onChangeText={(freeText) => setFreeText(freeText)}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }

    const onSendFeedbacck = async () => {
      if (!checkBoxStatus) {
        showErrorAlert("Your Response")
        return
      }
      if (!freeText) {
        showErrorAlert("Your Response")
        return
      }
      setLoading(true)

      console.log("<<< inside onSendFeedbacck >>>>>")
      // 1. display inputArray
      const inputArray = checkBoxStatus
      console.log("<<< inputArray >>>>>", inputArray)

      // 2. display inputArray Length
      // console.log("<<< items.length >>>>>", inputArray)

      const AnswerArray = inputArray

      console.log("AnswerArray ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArray)

      const AnswerArrayStr = JSON.stringify(AnswerArray)
      console.log("AnswerArrayStr ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArrayStr)

      const AnswerArrayObj = JSON.parse(AnswerArrayStr)
      console.log("AnswerArrayObj ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArrayObj)

      const dataToSend = {
        customerId: CustomerId,
        productDeviceId: DeviceId,
        questions: AnswerArrayObj,
        otherComments: freeText,
        salesAgentId: salesAgentId,
      }

      console.log("dataToSend ..>>>>>>>> ", dataToSend)
      try {
        console.log("<<<<<<<BEFORE RESPONSE FOR SEND FEEDBACK >>>>>>>>>")
        console.log("dataToSend >> ", dataToSend)
        console.log("config >> ", config)

        const res = await api.post("/", dataToSend, config)
        console.log(res)
        console.log("Res >> ", res)
        console.log("<<<<<<<AFTER RESPONSE FOR SEND_FEEDBACK_URL >>>>>>>>>")

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
        if (res.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
          // Get Response
          setLoading(false)
          getSuccessScreen()
        } else {
          console.log("<<<<<<<ERRRRRROR>>>>>>>>>")
          setLoading(false)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        setLoading(false)
        Alert.alert("Error " + err)
      }
    }

    return (
      <ImageBackground source={Images.bg} style={FULL}>
        <Loader loading={loading} />
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={BOTTOM_HALF}>
            <SafeAreaView>
              <Text style={SUBJECT}>Device Identified</Text>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>Barcode ID</Text>
                <Text style={REGULAR_TEXT}>{barcodeId}</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>Customer </Text>
                <Text style={REGULAR_TEXT}>{CustomerName}</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>
                  Please Fill the Form Below to by selecting an option between 1 to 5 for each
                  question to Provide More Information on This Device
                </Text>
              </View>

              {renderInputRadios()}

              <View style={FOOTER_CONTENT}>
                <Button
                  testID="next-screen-button"
                  style={CONTINUE}
                  textStyle={CONTINUE_TEXT}
                  tx="inside.send_feedback"
                  onPress={onSendFeedbacck}
                />
              </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    )
  },
)
```

Comment: You're hard-coding  radio button value `status={tempStr4 === "4" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}`. Selected Icon should be depend on state not manually typed string.

Comment: Hi . Please see https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button.html  thats the reference I used for radio buttons in react native paper

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?